# Sikuli resize region with nearby-function

Tags: region, sikuli

I have a region object, which has to be resized. It needs to be 20px smaller from every border. However the `Region.nearby()` function does only accept positive integer values, so the region can only become bigger, not smaller.
Is there any other function for resizing a region or a workaround to pass even negative integers to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the X,Y,H,W of the new region based on the old region with something like this:

```
oldRegion = SomeRegionYouAlreadyDefined
oldRegion.highlight(2) 
newRegion = Region((oldRegion.getX() + 20), (oldRegion.getY() + 20), (oldRegion.getW() - 40), (oldRegion.getH() - 40))
newRegion.highlight(2)
```

Of course, you can remove the .highlight() lines. That's just for ease of seeing where your regions are.

Comment: This works. However its not that straight forward as I expected^^

Comment: Yeah, it's bulky. I was just trying to think of a way that didn't use the nearby() function :)